# C++ Access Violation Reading location 0x003AE000 when trying to erase from vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am getting an error when I try to erase an item from an vector if the item is set to not alive by a boolean. I have tried searching the net but havn't found anything about it. I have tried to find different ways to delete elements on index x in a vector and found the function: vector.erase(vector.begin() + index)

So when I try using it in my for loop I get access violation reading location pointing at the erase function line.

Code for the loop where the error is:

```
    if (!player.getBullets().empty())
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < player.getBullets().size(); x++)
        {
            //Check for projectiles whos status is dead.
            if (!player.getBullets()[x]->getAlive())
            {
                //Erase the element at position x.
                player.getBullets().erase(player.getBullets().begin() + x);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should show much more code, you should compile with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`) and you should use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`) and show the backtrace given by it.

Comment: Mangling the container *while you're iterating over it* need a lot of care and attention to detail. Did you notice that your code fails to erase two consecutive elements?

Comment: The only thing i get is what I said, I get a pop up box (using visual studio 2013): 
`First-chance exception at 0x6298F189 (msvcr120.dll) in GameEngine_Prog2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0061E000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.`

Comment: Also, does GetBullets return by value, by any chance?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I get the error when I have shot a bullet and it collides with the wall and then it is set: alive = false and then in the for loop I've shown I go through and if a bullet is not alive then I want to remove it

Comment: @jrok: It returns a vector

Comment: @sandmaster A vector or a reference to a vector?

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: `vector<Projectile*> Sprite::getBullets()
 {
  return bullets;
 }`

The bullets is a vector<Projectile*>

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier to erase correctly if you use an iterator instead of an index.  An (almost) direct conversion of your code:

```
vector<Projectile*> bullets = player.getBullets();

for (vector<Projectile*>::iterator x = bullets.begin(); x != bullets.end(); )
{
    //Check for projectiles whos status is dead.
    if (!(*x)->getAlive())
    {
        //Erase the element at position x.
        x = bullets.erase(x);
    }
    else
    {
        ++ x;
    }
}
```

Note that this only works with a local copy of the vector.  If you want to update the vector in the player class itself, you will need to change `getBullets` to return a reference:

```
vector<Projectile*> &Sprite::getBullets()
{
    return bullets;
}
```

And then for the loop:

```
vector<Projectile*> &bullets = player.getBullets();
```

Comment: What would auto be ? :S

Comment: @sandmaster It's a C++11 feature to automatically determine the type when declaring a variable.  I used the `auto` keyword because I don't know the type of your vector, but if you tell me the type of your vector I can update the answer to avoid `auto`.

Comment: It seem to have worked, I was afraid my other for loops would have needed to be changed because the change of method. :/

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel, especially not the really difficult one that can go under water and up walls. Use a ready-made one:

```
#include <algorithm>

player.getBullets().erase(
    std::remove_if(player.getBullets().begin(),
                   player.getBullets().end(),
                   [](Projectile * p) -> bool { return !p->getAlive(); }),
    player.getBullets().end());
```

(I'm assuming that `Bullet` is the same as `decltype(player.getBullets())::value_type`, i.e. the element type of the bullets container. Adjust to suit.)

Comment: The container is filled with objects of the class Projectile; vector<Projectile*> but the remove_if says it is undefined

Comment: Cheers, it still says that "remove_if" is undefined :/ and If I have the std::remove_if it says: namespace "std" has no member "remove_if"

Comment: @sandmaster: Oh, sorry, you need to `#include <algorithm>`. Forgot to mention that :-S

Comment: That helped! :)
I ran the program again and now with that change I got the same error pointing on:

`return alive`

in method:

`bool Projectile::getAlive()
{
 return alive;
}`

Comment: @sandmaster Sounds like you have an invalid (already freed?) pointer in your bullets vector.  Running the program through valgrind might help to diagnose this.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: What I know I shouldn't have, the only place I am freeing my elements is in the remove method I am trying to get to work :) Otherwise I am just going through the vector and painting and updating the elements

Answer (score 0):

Though the loop is invalid because counter x is increased while the size of the vector is decreased and as the result not all the vector is traversed  I do not see the reason of the access violation. I think that the problem is related to objects stored in the vector.